# Development frameworks in C#

Tags: xna, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin, monogame

When I look for development in C#, I get the following terms/frameworks/libraries:

Xamarin

Mono

Monotouch

Monogame(for games)

Are there more?

My first doubt is that are Xamarin, Mono and Monotouch same? If no, what is the difference?

Secondly Monogame is open-source implementation of Microsoft XNA. What is the meaning of open-source implementation? And if it is XNA-like, then why cant we just use XNA and why is XNA being made obsolete?

Comment: Those are a lot of questions, none of which can't be solved with a few minutes of google.
Xamarin is a company that makes Mono, a (mostly) platform independent clone of microsoft's .NET framework.
MonoTouch is a framework to use MONO on iPhones and iPads.
Mono and .NET are not the same thing, so XNA (built for .NET) won't run on Mono without some modification.

Comment: I have heard many people say that no question is a dumb question. But stackoverflow proves them wrong. Users here give me atleast -1 for almost every question I ask. They wont let a beginner programmer turn great.

Comment: You get downvotes on questions that aren't welcome. these include open questions, or questions you could very easily find the answer to by reading the documentation or googling for a bit. be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: but google doesn't define "open source implementation"

Comment: it can still help you find out what that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For questions like this why not visit http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev who are generally happy to help with these kind of questions.

So [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) are the company that develop monogame which mentioned above is a clone of the now obsolete XNA framework which for some unknown reason MS have ditched. There isn't much work needed to port your XNA game to monogame. Developing for PC is free and always will be. You can pay for the tools required to develop on ios and android.

It really is a great cross platform choice especially if you have experience with XNA. For another C# alternative check out Unity.